# laravel @include not working for section('script')

Tags: php, laravel

My yield or section or include is not working here is my code I think I already follow all the rules. As you can see I want to call the three.blade.php I name it as a @section('script') and call it to the master.blade.php using yield('script') but it seems the yield or section is not working. here are my codes below:

master.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/css/bootstrap-select.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/fontawesome/css/all.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title> كاربران</title>
</head>
<body>
@include('Home.layouts.sidebar')
<main id="app">
    @include('Home.layouts.header')
    @yield('content')
</main>
@include('Home.layouts.footer')
@yield('script')
</body>
</html>
```

index.blade.php

```
@include('Home.steps.one')
@include('Home.steps.two')
@include('Home.steps.three')
```

two.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('book.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    ....
</form>

<table class="table table-striped">
    ....
</table>

@section('script')
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#book_id', function() {
            alert('Hello');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

three.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('requisition.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    ....
</form>

<table class="table table-striped">
    ....
</table>

@section('script')
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#province_id', function() {
            alert('Hello');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@include('Home.steps.one')
@include('Home.steps.two')
@include('Home.steps.three')


@endsection
```

and for script and css you can use `@stack`.So in `master.blade.php` instead of

```
@yield('script')
```

use

```
@stack("script")
```

and in `two.blade.php` or any master extended layout use

```
@push('script')
<script>

</script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

[@John Lobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16002199/john-lobo) is correct, `@stack` and `@push` are definitely the way to go here. But there is also one other thing that might be going on here. Looks like you're trying to use jQuery, but I don't see it being imported anywhere.